# Don't show ads if visitor is coming from careers profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

If an employer looking at a careers profile follows a link to a featured answer, and is new to Stack Overflow, the site will appear with the standard "drive-by visitor" ads, and the big orange "welcome" bar to the top.

We all know that compared to other sites, this is still paradise, but it would be great to have things completely nice and clean when a potential employer drops by: After all, the featured answer is to some extent part of the résumé.

Could the ads be tuned down to a logged-in 200+ rep  user's level for users who have a careers profile in their `HTTP_REFERER`?

Comment: What happens if they click a link on SO?  They end up on a page with ads because the referrer isn't careers anymore?

Comment: @Jason yes, any page beyond the initial question would get ads as usual. That's fair game IMO. No need to make it too complex, just a simple referrer check

Answer (score -6):

No. I wouldn't want to work for someone who doesn't know how to use [Adblock Plus](http://adblockplus.org/)

Comment: I'm fairly sure that would filter out a *lot* of good employers.

Comment: That really filter a lot of people. -1